# How to swap between photos in single page app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 thumbnail images in a row, that each image is related to another 4 images and I explain:
the main 4 images are characters in the game (warrior, swordsman, etc') and I want to click on warrior image and move on in the same page to the warrior gear page(armor, boots weapons, etc'). I try a lot of methods here but still no success.
can someone please try to help me?

```js
count = 1;
total = 4;

$(".img-swap1").on('click', function() {

  $(this).fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'images/swordsman' + count + '.jpg');
  }).fadeIn(400);
  count++;
  if (count > total) {
    count = 1;
  }
});
```

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 18%;
  padding: 14px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 40%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Clear floats after image containers */

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/swordsman.jpg" class="img-swap1" alt="Swordsman" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/Mage-0.png" class="img-swap" alt="Mage" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/Warrior-0.png" class="img-swap" alt="Warrior" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/GhostFighter-0.png" class="img-swap" alt="GhostFighter" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your approach is more `single page` rather than `single page application`. Learn more about SPA, routing and data layers.

Comment: Where is your javascript?

Comment: there is not JS because I don't know yet in what method to use, that's why I ask here.

Comment: but you said "I try a lot of methods"...so what did you try? You can't do this without JavaScript. Even if your code didn't work very well, it's better to show it, then maybe we can fix it quickly for you (rather than starting again from the beginning). Show us your best attempt, please. But you know for this kind of thing probably you can just download an image carousel library which will implement it all for you easily

Comment: ok, i show you 1 method that i find here, it makes the job but not exactly what i need. so i manage to swap image by add imagename+1 so when you press on the first image you move to the second. i need when you press on first image the page will change and show you new 4 images (related to the first image)

Comment: Do you simply want to scroll down to the warrior or really replace the picture?

Comment: so what exactly does it do, and what exactly did you want it to do instead? You've only given us a very basic description of the requirement, and none at all about what is wrong with the code you've written. As far as I can see though, one obvious issue is that it will only work with the first picture, and not the others, You need to make it more generic.

Comment: @Daidon I want that when you click on the first image it will swap all the 4 images, for example, the first image is "Animals" when you click on it you will show 4 different animals images (same place of the image before) and now when you have Fish, Birds, etc' you click on Fish image and it shows you in a table all the Fish species. now it's better explanation?

Comment: Here you can see exactly what I want to do in a single page using JS/JQuery: https://xiah-resurgence.fandom.com/wiki/Items

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an array of objects, that contain both: the link to the image and also the name of the subset.

This way, for the future, you can simply get your array from a json.

Implementation would be like:

```js
var sets = [];

sets['default'] = [
{
  link: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/fantasy-rpg-game-character-monsters-450w-1220706547.jpg",
  set: "swordsman"
},
{
 link: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/fantasy-rpg-game-character-monsters-450w-1220706535.jpg",
  set: "swordsman"
},
{
 link: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/fantasy-rpg-game-character-monsters-450w-1221331996.jpg",
  set: "swordsman"
},
{
 link: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/fantasy-rpg-game-character-monsters-450w-1220706532.jpg",
  set: "swordsman"
} 
];

sets['swordsman'] = [
{
  link: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/hero-swordsman-bright-armor-medieval-450w-1288381915.jpg",
  set: "default"
},
{
 link: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/hero-swordsman-bright-armor-medieval-450w-1288381921.jpg",
  set: "default"
},
{
 link: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/hero-swordsman-bright-armor-medieval-450w-1288381924.jpg",
  set: "default"
},
{
 link: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/hero-swordsman-bright-armor-medieval-450w-1288381930.jpg",
  set: "default"
} 
];

$(".img-swap").click(function() {replaceImgSet(this);});

function replaceImgSet(obj) {
var _clicked_elem = obj;
  $(obj).parent().parent().fadeOut(400, function() {
   var rset = $(_clicked_elem).data("set");
    var rowdiv = $(obj).parent().parent();
    rowdiv.children(".column").remove();
    sets[rset].forEach(function(elem) {
     var imgdiv = $('<div class="column"></div>');
      var img = $('<img src="'+elem.link+'" data-set="'+elem.set+'" class="img-swap" alt="Mage" style="width:100%">');
      img.click(function() {replaceImgSet(this)});
     $(rowdiv).append(imgdiv.append(img));
    });
    $(rowdiv).fadeIn();
  });
}
```

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 18%;
  padding: 14px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Clear floats after image containers */

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/fantasy-rpg-game-character-monsters-450w-1220706547.jpg" class="img-swap" data-set="swordsman" alt="Swordsman" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/fantasy-rpg-game-character-monsters-450w-1220706535.jpg" class="img-swap" data-set="swordsman" alt="Mage" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/fantasy-rpg-game-character-monsters-450w-1221331996.jpg" class="img-swap" data-set="swordsman" alt="Warrior" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/fantasy-rpg-game-character-monsters-450w-1220706532.jpg" class="img-swap" data-set="swordsman" alt="GhostFighter" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```